# How to change behavior of Azure Devops to report tests run with DataTestMethod attribute as seperate tests

Tags: azure-devops, mstest

I have a MSTest test that uses the DataTestMethod attribute to dynamically generate a matrix of values to test a function with. I could describe it generally like

Example:

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DynamicData(nameof(DynamicTestData), DyanmicDataSourceType.Property]
public void Run_test_on_function_xzy(int input, int expected)
{
    // Run test using the to input values.
}
```

For purpose of discussion, I'll say DyanmicTestData returns 10 values, which results in 10 tests being run.

Now on the Azure Devops side when I run the tests in Azure Pipeline, Azure Devops reports only one test result, not 10. Is there a way, I can modify this behavior in MSTest or Azure DevOps to report a Result for each subtest at the root level?

Answer (score 0):

> Azure Devops reports only one test result, not 10. Is there a way, I can modify this behavior in MSTest or Azure DevOps to report a Result for each subtest at the root level?

Check the pic below, in the build summary page, we could see the test run, and expend it, we could see the test result. We cannot report the result for each subtest at the root level, the root level shows the test run instead of test result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response Vito.

What I expected to see was more like

Just a test.IndexPageTest
Just a test.AboutPageTest
Just a test.ContactPageTest
etc..

There are some benefits to this. For example if there is a bug in ContactsPageTest a bug association can be made to that test. In the current logic the bug association is made to Just a test instead!

Comment: Hi @loganwol, it seems that we cannot do this now, You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.