# Running test using TestDataMethod in MSTest in Azure-Devops

Tags: azure-devops, mstest, test-data

I have an API test that run within Azure Devops pipeline using TestDataMethod within MSTest. My tests run fine, but problem is all tests reported have the same name, so kind of difficult to figure out which test failed. This works fine in Visual Studio in my local. Is there a way to fix this? I found an [old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66909782/how-to-change-behavior-of-azure-devops-to-report-tests-run-with-datatestmethod-a) for the same issue but has no solution.

Screenshot

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see we cannot report the result for each subtest at the root level which also mentioned in the ticket you mentioned. For more information about test result, you could refer to [Test analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/test-analytics?view=azure-devops), which provides near real-time visibility into your test data for builds and releases. It helps improve the efficiency of your pipeline by identifying repetitive, high impact quality issues.

Comment: I am already using that feature but that also doesn't point to individual test for TestDataMethod. Hope this capability will be added in future. Thanks !